# How to remove spaces at the end of folder names?

Tags: linux, scripting, directory, rename

I would like to delete the spaces at the end of my folder names.

I have a folder called "Project1 " in which I have another folder called "Exercise1 ".

I want to use a script to delete the spaces at the end and only at the end.
I don't know if I have expressed myself correctly.

Thank you in advance, have a nice evening.

I typed the command `/bin/ls -l | od -c`

```
root@debian:~$ /bin/ls -l | od -c
0000000   t   o   t   a   l       3   2  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x
0000020   r   -   x       2       k   a   b   i   a       k   a   b   i
0000040   a       4   0   9   6       j   u   i   l   .       2   0    
0000060   1   0   :   2   6       B   u   r   e   a   u  \n   d   r   w
0000100   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       7       k   a   b   i   a    
0000120   k   a   b   i   a       4   0   9   6       j   u   i   l   .
0000140       2   2       1   7   :   4   6       D   o   c   u   m   e
0000160   n   t   s  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       2
0000200       k   a   b   i   a       k   a   b   i   a       4   0   9
0000220   6       j   u   i   l   .       2   2       1   9   :   2   6
0000240       I   m   a   g   e   s  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x   r
0000260   -   x       2       k   a   b   i   a       k   a   b   i   a
0000300       4   0   9   6       j   u   i   l   .       2   0       1
0000320   0   :   2   6       M   o   d 303 250   l   e   s  \n   d   r
0000340   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       2       k   a   b   i   a
0000360       k   a   b   i   a       4   0   9   6       j   u   i   l
0000400   .       2   0       1   0   :   2   6       M   u   s   i   q
0000420   u   e  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       2    
0000440   k   a   b   i   a       k   a   b   i   a       4   0   9   6
0000460       j   u   i   l   .       2   0       1   0   :   2   6    
0000500   P   u   b   l   i   c  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -
0000520   x       2       k   a   b   i   a       k   a   b   i   a    
0000540   4   0   9   6       j   u   i   l   .       2   0       1   0
0000560   :   2   6       T 303 251   l 303 251   c   h   a   r   g   e
0000600   m   e   n   t   s  \n   d   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x
0000620       2       k   a   b   i   a       k   a   b   i   a       4
0000640   0   9   6       j   u   i   l   .       2   0       1   0   :
0000660   2   6       V   i   d 303 251   o   s  \n
0000673
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '**/*[[:space:]]' '${f%%[[:space:]]#}'
```

(remove `-n` for dry-run when happy)

Would remove trailing whitespace characters from the end of every non hidden file or directory. Add `(#q/)` to the pattern argument if you want to restrict to directories only. Or `(#qD)` to also process hidden file.

POSIXly, you can do something approaching with:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name '*[[:space:]]' -exec sh -x -c '
  for f do
    : mv -i "$f" "${f%"${f##*[![:space:]]}"}"
  done' sh {} +
```

(remove `-x` and `:` when happy).

That one is limited to ASCII whitespace characters.

Comment: Hello,

I have taken into account your answer and thank you. However, it still doesn't work. When I run my script, my folders with spaces at the end are not renamed.
Also, I am trying to run this code in bash. I am testing things on my side but I am still at the same point.
But thank you very much for your answers and your reactivity.

Answer (score 3):

##### You can do this using a Bash script.

Just create a script and copy this code in it, put it in the top directory in which the "bad named directories" are located, then execute:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
# find all directory names that end with space:
while find "$(pwd)" -type d |grep  -q ' $'
do
    # select one and store its name in DIR variable
    DIR=$(find "$(pwd)" -type d | grep ' $'|head -1)
    
    # remove the last character (which is space) from that 
    # name and save it to NEW_DIR variable
    NEW_DIR=${DIR%?}
    
    # rename the directory
    mv "$DIR" "$NEW_DIR"
done
```

As you can see in this screenshot, there were directories which had similar conditions in "*test2*" directory, and the script named "space.sh" is also located in "*test2*". After executing the script, directories have been renamed as we desired:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `pathlib` module in **python3**  has all the wherewithal to walk the hierarchy , detect the said files, and rename them.

```
python3 -c 'import pathlib
for p in iter(pathlib.Path(".").rglob("*[ \t]")):
  p.rename("/".join([str(p.parent),p.name.rstrip()]))'
```

Based on the kinds of filenames present in your file hierarchy, we use the following piece of python to recursively traverse the tree depth first is the default action . It looks for any non-ASCII names and renames by replacing he nonASCII char. with an "X". No checks are made before renaming whether the new name already exists.

```
python3 - <<\eof
import pathlib, re
for p in iter(pathlib.Path('.').rglob('*[! -~]*')):
  foo = p.name
  for m in re.finditer(r"[^ -~]",p.name):
    foo = foo[:m.start()] + "X" + foo[m.end():]
  p.rename("/".join([str(p.parent),foo]))
eof
```

Comment: Hello,

I have taken into account your two answers and thank you. However, it still doesn't work. When I run my script, my folders with spaces at the end are not renamed.
Also, I am trying to run this code in bash. I am testing things on my side but I am still at the same point.
But thank you very much for your answers and your reactivity.

Comment: Well that means there are not real spaces at the end of file names then. Can you share the output of the command `/bin/ls -l | od -c`

Comment: The output is very big, I think I can't share it

Comment: Can you share a clipped output? Obtained via piping the od -c output to head? Because I want to know what characters comprise your filenames exactly.

Comment: Yes I can, I will put a little part.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895).

I didn't write this but I use it a lot. Transferring video files from a Windows box to my Linux box puts extra white spaces at the end of directory names and this command removes them whether it's a single white space or multiple white spaces at the end of folder and file names.

Remove empty spaces at the end of directory / file names in the current directory

does a dry run

```
rename -n 's/ *$//' ./*
```

actual run

```
rename 's/ *$//' ./*
```